# Cannot access tables on command line on SQLite

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite

I created database in C++ using following code in c:\tmp. Also created table and can access table in C++. But when I try to access that table via SQLite command line I get "no such table " error.

Here is how I create db in C++

```
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2("file:///C:/tmp/myTest1.db", &db,  SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE| SQLITE_OPEN_URI, NULL );
    if( rc ){
       printf(  "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       return(0);
    }else{
       printf(  "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

    /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "CREATE TABLE LoadDates("  \
     "ID           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
     "DT            INT     NOT NULL  );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
       printf(  "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
       sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }else{
      printf(  "Table created successfully\n");
 }

 sql = "INSERT INTO LoadDates (ID,DT) "  \
     "VALUES ('A1', 20160701 ); " \
     "INSERT INTO LoadDates (ID,DT) "  \
     "VALUES ('A2', 20160601 ); " \
     "INSERT INTO  LoadDates (ID,DT) "  \
     "VALUES ('A3', 20160801  );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      printf( "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }else{
      printf(  "Records created successfully\n");
  }
```

Then when I access to access LoadDates via command line I get following error. I can see myTest1.db in c:\tmp directory

```
c:\tmp>sqlite3.exe myTest1
SQLite version 3.13.0 2016-05-18 10:57:30
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from LoadDates;
Error: no such table: LoadDates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full filename when calling `sqlite3.exe` on the command line:

```
C:\temp> sqlite3.exe myTest1.db
```